# Django search field changes to none after first pagination

Tags: django, django-views

I have a search form with several fields and developed a search view that allows searching on any combination of fields. This works and delivers the results as expected, until the first navigation (with the 'next' button) to the next page of the pagination created object. After navigating to 'next' the 'ct' field changes to 'None'. Here is the view:

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    yr = request.GET.get('yr', 0)
    ct = request.GET.get('ct')
    question_set = Uroquiz.objects.all()

    if q:
        if not (yr or ct):
            question_set = Uroquiz.objects.filter(question__icontains=q)

    if yr:
        if not (q or ct):
            question_set = Uroquiz.objects.filter(year=yr)

    if ct:
        if not (q or yr):
            question_set = Uroquiz.objects.filter(cat__icontains=ct)

    if (q and yr):
        if not ct:
            question_set = Uroquiz.objects.filter(question__icontains=q).filter(year=yr)

    if (q and ct):
        if not yr:
            question_set = Uroquiz.objects.filter(question__icontains=q).filter(cat__icontains=ct)
    if (yr and ct):
        if not q:
            question_set = Uroquiz.objects.filter(year=yr).filter(cat__icontains=ct)
    if ((q and yr) and ct):
        question_set = Uroquiz.objects.filter(question__icontains=q).filter(year=yr).filter(cat__icontains=ct)
    if not ((q or yr) or ct):
            return render_to_response('search_form.html')
    paginator = Paginator(question_set, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        question_set = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        question_set = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        question_set = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('search_results.html',
        {'question': question_set, 'q': q, 'yr': yr, 'ct': ct})
```

and here is the relevant portion of my search_results.html:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if question.has_previous %}
            <a href="?q={{ q }}&yr={{ yr }}&cat={{ ct }}&page={{ question.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ question.number }} of {{ question.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>

        {% if question.has_next %}
            <a href="?q={{ q }}&yr={{ yr }}&cat={{ ct }}&page={{ question.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. my url should use 'ct' not 'cat'. Simple mistake. Thanks to everyone who looked at this for me.